# How to separate edit and update contexts (admin-on-rest, dot notation)

Tags: javascript, rest, admin-on-rest, elixir

I am using npm package [admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest) to build react back-office for my elixir/phoenix REST API backend.

My questions/:id (`show action`) returns the following flat JSON structure:

```
{
  id: 7
  content: "<p> Question content here</p>"
  points: 300
  title: "Question title"
}
```

And my `update action` expects the following nested JSON as an input to update question:

```
{
  id: 7
  question: {
    content: "<p>New question content</p>"
    points: 400
    title: "New question title"
  }
}
```

---

My problem is related to dot notation used in `admin-on-rest`

If I use the following JS code to represent `edit` action within my back-office

```
export const QuestionEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit title={<QuestionTitle />} {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <DisabledInput source="question.id" />
      <TextInput source="question.title" />
      <LongTextInput source="question.content"/>
      <TextInput source="question.points" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
)
```

then I have correct data within PUT request payload, but there is no values rendered in "edit" form inputs (see screenshot 1)

[image]
[image]

And if I use another variant of JS code (with flat source values):

```
export const QuestionEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit title={<QuestionTitle />} {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <DisabledInput source="id" />
      <TextInput source="title" />
      <LongTextInput source="content"/>
      <TextInput source="points" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
)
```

then all previous input values in "edit" form represented correctly, but PUT request payload cannot be parsed by my `update` action (see screenshot 2)

[image]
[image]

---

Assuming that I don't want to change my backend API (because it is auto-generated by phoenix code generators), how can I edit my JS code to achieve 2 goals - previous values should be rendered correctly (edit page) and nested JSON structure should be provided for `update` action

Many thanks in advance for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at using a custom [action](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Actions.html#using-a-custom-action-creator).  Basically your form is rendering with data that is flattened, hence why it will show correctly when you use (`id`, `title`, etc.).  Then you need to transform that data before you `PUT` it to your server.